# Is there an efficient way to print out chars repeatidly without a loop?

Tags: php

Is there a way I can simplify this function in PHP?

This function will return a string with x dots.

```
function dots($num)
{
   for($i = 0; $i < $num; $i++)
       $dot .= ".";   
   return $dot;
}
dot(10000);
```

Is there a better way to print 10000 dots without a loop? This seems inefficient

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
function dots($num) {
    return str_repeat(".", $num);
}

echo dots(10000);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [str_repeat](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-repeat.php) function:

```
echo str_repeat(".", 10);
```